# Can an AclEntryVoter processConfigAttribute be used in @PostFilter in a hasPermission expression?

Tags: spring, spring-security, acl

I'm using Spring Security 4.0.2.RELEASE.

I've defined a custom AclEntryVoter like this one:

```
<bean id="aclReadVoter" class="org.springframework.security.acls.AclEntryVoter">
    <constructor-arg ref="aclService" />
    <constructor-arg value="VOTE_ACL_READ" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.BasePermission.READ" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="processDomainObjectClass" value="com.example.domain.MyDomainObject" />
</bean>
```

In a `@Service` class, I want to use the processConfigAttribute `VOTE_ACL_READ`  as a permission inside a @`PostFilter` method, something like this:

```
@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'VOTE_ACL_READ')")
public List<MyDomainObject> findAll() {
    ...
}
```

However, when trying to do that, I'm getting an

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown permission 'VOTE_ACL_READ'

  org.springframework.security.acls.domain.DefaultPermissionFactory.buildFromName(DefaultPermissionFactory.java:133)
```

The `DefaultPermissionFactory.buildFromName` is being passed `VOTE_ACL_READ`  whereas I was expecting it to receive `org.springframework.security.acls.domain.BasePermission.READ` as defined inside the custom `AclEntryVoter`.

Is it even possible to use the `VOTE_ACL_READ` processConfigAttribute as a permission inside a hasPermission expression ? If yes, how ?